# Definition of a private access modifier

Tags: c#

Is this definition for a private access modifier accurate?:

*private: Any thing declared as private can’t be seen outside of its class.*

What about a private nested class?

This class can be seen "outside of its own class" by the class that is nesting it.

Maybe you could say that this nested class is actually a private member of the class nesting it and therefore can't be seen outside of the nesting class which would make the definition provided above true.

If a private nested class is NOT considered a member of the nesting class then I think the definition provided above is not accurate.

Comment: which programming language are you using? or do you want a generic answer?

Comment: @ErdincAy It's in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe you could say that this nested class is actually a private member of the class nesting it and therefore can't be seen outside of the nesting class.

That's exactly what it means.